# xserver: 1280x720 on 1280x1024 monitor (letterbox)

Tags: linux, xorg

I try to run a game in a separate X server. The issue is that i need to run it at 16:9 aspect, otherwise it runs with artifacts.
I start the game in windowed mode at 1280x720 on a bare xserver. So I have a borderless window in the upper part of the screen. I just need to shift it down 152 pixels to have a proper "letterbox".
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Does that mean you are just running an X server without a window manager or are you using Xnest or Xephyr?

Comment: plain X with no wm

Comment: If you're lucky the game may respond to standard X options. Many use -geometry 1280x720+0+152

Comment: @parkydr that was the first thing I tried